# JSON object flattening or creation with javascript

Tags: javascript, json

Object:

```js
{
    firstName: "Doe",
    address: "California",
    mobile: "xxxx"
}
```

List of objects or Array:

```js
[
  { name: "course1", value: "1" } ,
  { name: "course2", value: "2" } ,
  { name: "course3", value: "3" }
]
```

Expected output or object from:

```
{
  firstName: "Doe",
  address: "California",
  mobile: "xxxx",
  course1: "1",
  course2: "2",
  course3: "3"
}
```

I want to achieve above object using javascript.

Thank you !

Comment: Please show us your attempt, otherwise we can't help you improve your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `map()` and `Object.assign()` like the following way:

```js
var obj = { firstName : "Doe", address : "California", mobile : "xxxx" };
var arr = [{name : "course1",value : "1"} , {name : "course2",value : "2"} , {name : "course3",value : "3"}];

arr = arr.map(v => ({[v.name]: v.value}));
var newObj = Object.assign(obj, Object.assign({}, ...arr));
console.log(newObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the expected output using [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [`Computed property names`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names).

```js
let data = { firstName : "Doe", address : "California", mobile : "xxxx" };
let courses = [{name : "course1",value : "1"} , {name : "course2",value : "2"} , {name : "course3",value : "3"}];

const finalRes = courses.reduce((res, obj) => {
  return {
    ...res,
    [obj.name]: obj.value
  };
}, {...data});

console.log(finalRes)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can map the values of each object to entries and then turn those into an object using `Object.fromEntries`. After you have that new object, apply it to the original.

```js
const sourceObject = {
  firstName: "Doe",
  address: "California",
  mobile: "xxxx"
};

const propArray = [
  { name: "course1", value: "1" } ,
  { name: "course2", value: "2" } ,
  { name: "course3", value: "3" }
];

const resultObject = {
  ...sourceObject,
  ...Object.fromEntries(propArray.map(p => Object.values(p)))
};

console.log(resultObject);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```